# Show that the following set defines a Topology in X

Tags: general-topology

I have $\tau:=${$Y \in P(x)| A \subseteq Y$} $\cup $ {$\emptyset$}.
$X$ is a set and $A\subseteq X$ . And also P(x) is the power set of X. I have to show that $\tau$ defines a topology in X.

I thought about proving the 3 conditions of a topology.

$01)$ Since A is a subset of X and X is a subset of its power set, than $X \in \tau$ and also $\emptyset \in \tau $ because of definition of $\tau$.

$02)$ random many unions of subsets of $\tau$ remain in $\tau$. I thought about it that subsets of $\tau$ would be also subsets of the power set and would have A in them. Their union would be part of the power set and would contain A and therefore would fufill the condition to be in $\tau$.

$03)$ finite intersections of sets of $\tau$ will remain in $\tau$.
For this third one i have no clue. I thought that maybe A would be the set of this finite intersections since it is an element of all of the sets but I have no idea if this is true.

I also don't know if the other ones are correct. I really have difficulties with Topology so some help and explanation would be very appreciated.

Thank you in advance,

Annalisa

Comment: Just write down the definitions. For the third one for example, you have to take $X_1, ..., X_n$ subsets of $X$ containing $A$, and to show that $\cap_{i=1}^n X_i$ is a subset of $X$ containing $A$. Isn't that clear ?

Answer (score 1):

With two sets is enough to show finite intersection. Let $ U, V \in \tau$, if $ U = \emptyset $ or $V = \emptyset $ then $ U \cap V = \emptyset \in \tau$ so suppose $ U ≠ \emptyset $ and $V ≠ \emptyset $ so $A \subset U  $ and $ A \subset V$ then $ A = A \cap A \subset U \cap V$ and by definition $ U\cap V \in \tau$